# Looking for inventory control for for search and rescue equipment (preferably identifying users by bar code)

Tags: inventory

Sorry if I haven't done this properly.
I am looking for a simple software solution that is similar to a library system for our Search and Rescue teams.

Member have ID cards (like a library card) with a barcode attached.
We also have a large room full on expensive equipment with barcodes on them.

Ideally, we would like a kiosk that when someone take gear from the storage, they scan their ID card and then scan the equipment they are taking.
When they return the gear, they can scan their card and then scan the gear back in.

The solution needs to be taken into the bush and used 'offline' as we often load the equipment into a truck and take it into the mountains where we deploy teams.

Comment: Where will they scan their Id card? Are you open to issuing new cards if required (I am thinking RFID, instead of barcode)? It need some sort of computing device. A PC seems unlikely in the bush, unless you plan to run it from a car battery. Maybe a laptop, maybe a smartphone (which kind)? Or are you asking us to recommend that too? Do you seek only a cost-free solution, or do you have a budget?

Comment: Is there anything Search & Rescue specific here, or are you juts looking for inventory control? (don't forget, you will have to be able to add/move new/broken equipment, in addition to borrow/return). The better that you can specify your requirements, the better that we can help you

Comment: everyone has an ID card with a barcode on it. this is issued as part of the national training program - so we will need to add new users from time to time. We have laptops so I was intending on using one of those. I am seeking a low cost solution

Comment: Yes sorry, we are looking for inventory control - we would need to add/remove items and would want to track when an item was purhcased and be able to run a report of all the items we have and maybe add a initial cost (purchase cost) with the item

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:linux/freshness:recently-updated/?q=inventory  (you might have to change the o/s in that link)